# Chat block divider in a Chat-Enabled Notebook using Swedish keyboard

Tags: notebooks, llmfunction

(I'm using Mathematica 13.3.0 on a Linux Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, using a Swedish keyboard.)

In a Chat-Enabled Notebook, the "~" (the tilde character) is used to create a Chat block divider/ChatDelimiter for creating a new fresh session in a notebook (thus forgetting all the previous chats/text in the notebook).

This works when the computer is set up for an English keyboard (then using Shift-1), but not when using a Swedish keyboard, since the "~" character is then a "lazy" character: it's generated by the keyboard combination of "Alt-Gr + ^" and then pressing Space (so we can write combined characters such as "ñ"). This generates the "~" character in an input field, i.e. not the chat block divider.

Is there a way to generate the chat block divider using a Swedish keyboard?

The "~" is not mentioned in the help page for the LLM-Releated Functionality (guide/LLMFunctions), so perhaps it's not an official supported function?

Related: When doing a mouse over a generated Chat block divider, the text in the Style drop down is shown as "ChatDelimiter", but that is not possible to select when the mouse marker is in a free space of the notebook.